# Unable to add an extra column to an existing CSV file

Tags: powershell, csv

I have a `.csv` file which contains data as below:

```
Name ID
ABC 1234
CDE 3456
```

I am trying to insert a column called "Date" as the first column.

```
Date        Name     ID
2018-03-28  ABC     1234
2018-03-28  CDE     3456
```

I am using below import-export:

```
$a = Import-Csv -Path c:\filename.csv -Header Date,Name,Id
$a | Export-Csv -Path c:\outfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

But above not working as expected. It's displacing the column data.

```
Date  Name  Id
ABC   1234
CDE   3456
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add the property to the objects:

```
$a= import-csv -path c:\filename.csv -header Name,Id
foreach($item in $a){
    Add-Member -Input $item -MemberType NoteProperty -Name Date -Value '2018-03-28'
}
$a | Select-Object Date, Name, ID | export-csv -path c:\outfile.csv -Notypeinformation
```

Comment: Date is coming as column number 3 but I need it as the first column.

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of [calculated properties](https://workingsysadmin.com/calculated-properties-in-powershell/) like this -

```
Import-Csv -path C:\filename.csv |
Select-Object *,@{Name='Date';Expression={'2018-03-28'}} | 
Select-Object Date, Name, ID |
Export-Csv -path C:\Outfile.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: I am getting output like below                                                                                  ABC1234      Date                                                                                            CDE3456   2018-03-28

Comment: To change the positions of the columns, you can further add a `Select-Object` cmdlet and rearrange the columns as desired. Have a look at the answer after the edit.