# How to add data to last column of CSV using PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, command-line, command-line-interface

I have a requirement to add data to the last column of a CSV file. The test file I have looks like:

```
NAME,AGE,OFFICE,DEPT,SKILL
jack,24,IBM,Retail
tom,32,MS,BFSI
SAM,44,MGR,Test
```

I have managed to parse the CSV but then adding data to the last column "SKILL" is difficult. The requirement is to add the word 'Java' to the last column on each row

```
NAME,AGE,OFFICE,DEPT,SKILL
jack,24,IBM,Retail,Java
tom,32,MS,BFSI,Java
SAM,44,MGR,Test,Java
```

Please note that the value added to the last column remains the same across rows.

Comment: What have you managed to do so far? Can you read the file? Is modification the problem? Saving it?

Comment: I have managed to parse the csv but then adding data to the last column "SKILL" is seemingly difficult. The requirement is to add the word 'Java' to the last column on each row

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49541446/powershell-unable-to-add-an-extra-column-to-an-existing-csv-file/49541729#49541729

Comment: Please don't add irrelevant tags. Powershell-v2.0 and -v3.0 are version specific tags and only to be used when no other versions can be used. command-line and command-line-interface have little relevance to the actual question.

Answer (score 3):

You can change the value of `SKILL` property of the imported objects, and export to CSV file by this:

```
Import-Csv test.txt |
    ForEach-Object {$_.SKILL = "Java"; $_} |
    Export-Csv test_out.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

However `Export-Csv` adds quotation marks around the values, so `test_out.txt` would look like this:

```
"NAME","AGE","OFFICE","DEPT","SKILL"
"jack","24","IBM","Retail","Java"
"tom","32","MS","BFSI","Java"
"SAM","44","MGR","Test","Java"
```

Maybe you should simply add `",Java`" to the end of each line second line onwards:

```
Get-Content test.txt |
    ForEach-Object { if($_.ReadCount -gt 1) { "$($_),Java" } else { $_ } } |
    Out-File test_out.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create an object that contains the current csv-data and extend that object with the string `Java` like so:

```
$results = @() # Empty array to store new created rows in
$csv = Import-Csv "$PSScriptRoot\csvfile.csv"
foreach ($row in $csv) {
    $properties = [ordered]@{
        NAME   = $row.NAME
        AGE    = $row.AGE
        OFFICE = $row.OFFICE
        DEPT   = $row.DEPT
        SKILL  = "Java"
    }
    # insert the new row as an object into the results-array
    $results += New-Object psobject -Property $properties
}
# foreach-loop filled the results-array - export it as a CSV-file
$results | Export-Csv "new-file.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```